# how to locate HTML from inspect element?

Tags: html, find, element, inspect, locate

How do I locate this part of the code in my theme? 
I want to delete it. 
But i can't find it...

[screenshot of the inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYoZf.png)

Comment: Code should be here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Joomla or Wordpress, you can't change the code. The only way to 'delete' your code is to use display:none; and hide the code.

//I can't comment so I have to post it as answer. Sorry.